# Heteroscedastic censored regression

Tags: r, heteroscedasticity, censoring, quantile-regression

I am dealing with a heteroscedastic censored dataset. I tried to use the survival analysis package in R to estimate a linear model for it. So before doing that, I conducted a simulation study, where I generate a sample for x:
$x  \sim Unif[-2,2]$
and y:
$y \sim 1+0.3x+0.6(1-0.3x)\epsilon $ where $\epsilon\sim N(0,1)$.
y is censored as $y=y$ if $y<x$; $y=x$ otherwise.

Then I use the survreg function in R to estimate a linear model for it.

`x<-runif(10000,-2,2)`

`y<-1+0.3*x+rnorm(length(x))*0.6*(1-0.3*x)`

`y[y>=x]=x[y>=x]`

`fit<-survreg(Surv(y, y<x, type='right')~x, dist='gaussian')`

The result is really poor, the estimate is around(intercept = 0.5, slope = 0.6) and it is very stable no matter what initial points I gave.

The result does not get significant improved even if I feed the true weight to it:

`fit<-survreg(Surv(y, y<x, type='right')~x, dist='gaussian', 'weights=1/(1-0.3x)^2')`

But the estimation is great when no heteroscedasticity is presented:

`x<-runif(10000,-2,2)`

`y<-1+0.3*x+rnorm(length(x))*0.6`

`y[y>=x]=x[y>=x]`

`fit<-survreg(Surv(y, y<x, type='right')~x, dist='gaussian')`

I also tried quantile regression for censored data with tau=0.5. (basically LAD regression which is proposed by J.Powell 1984). The result is still poor under this parameter setting.

Is there any good way to get a consistent estimation for heteroscedastic censored data?

Any suggestion on package, software or papers are welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might consider using Laplace regression, which is so far available only in Stata. It is one of the possible methods for conditional quantiles of censored outcomes and among its advantages there is the possibility of modeling the sigma parameter to account for possible heteroskedasticity.In Stata this is easily done. More information on Laplace regression are here: http://www.imm.ki.se/biostatistics/laplace/